# Backup up Transaction logs

Tags: sql-server-2005, backup

Is it possible copy the physical Transaction log file for SQL 2005?

Currently our databases are backed up every night with hourly Transaction logs taken during the day.  Is it possible that after the hourly backup has been done that the physical log file can be copied to another server? what steps would need to be taken to get this to work

Thanks

Andrew

Comment: What is it your looking to achieve by copying the log - are you looking to implement something like log shipping to get the hourly data accessible on another server?

Comment: FYI--this kind of question really belongs on our sister site, ServerFault.com

But anyway, not sure where you're going with this--you want to move the backups of the t-logs after you've made them? You can do that, but SQL Agent is not going to do it for you--it'd be better to make a simple batch script as a Scheduled Task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To copy to another Sql Server? If so, what you are after is [transaction log shipping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190016(SQL.90).aspx)

The transaction log backup captures the log at a certain point in time, however the log is still required to give the complete picture of the data in the database so it can't be moved. If you want to move it, stop any applications that are accessing the database's data, take the database offline, detach it, move the files and re-attach it.

Comment: Thanks.  I will look into log shipping.  I think thats what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

What Chris said. If you're asking whether it's a space problem, you'll need to take transaction log backups more often. Don't shrink the transaction logs, because they'll just grow again.